# Add a delay to menubar dropdown in fullscreen apps

Tags: macos, menu-bar, fullscreen

In Lion, the menubar drops down way to fast when I'm in a fullscreen app. This mostly becomes a problem when I have multiple tabs open in Terminal. When I move to the top to change tabs, the menubar drops down and I click it on accident. So is there any way to add a delay to the menubar dropping down? Or maybe change the drop down hotspot to one of the corners instead of just the top edge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible in Lion.

For your specific problem, I'd just use the keyboard shortcuts to move to a new tab; it's much faster anyway.

To move to the next tab, <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>}</kbd>. To move to the previous tab, <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>{</kbd>.

Comment: Yeah keyboard shortcuts help with that specific problem but there are other times the menu bar is bothersome. I'll give you a vote up for the shortcut though :)