# OS X Lion Fullscreen App's Menu Bar - Increase wait time?

Tags: macos, fullscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a delay to menubar dropdown in fullscreen apps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35242/add-a-delay-to-menubar-dropdown-in-fullscreen-apps)

When you make an application full screen in Lion, you can move your cursor to the very top of the screen, wait about half a second, and the app's menu bar will pop down.

Is there any way to increase the wait time between when I move my cursor to the top of the screen and when the menu bar pops down? I find myself trying to switch tabs in Chrome and getting the menu bar to pop down by accident (so far, my only real Lion annoyance =p)