# Add a Delay for Displaying the Menu Bar When App is in Fullscreen Mode

Tags: macos, fullscreen

When I work with an application in fullscreen mode (e.g. IntelliJ IDEA on macOS Sierra), the menu bar is hidden and shown only when I move the mouse cursor to the top of the screen.

The menu bar pops up after a short delay, *but* to my taste, that delay is way *too* short. I constantly trigger the menu bar by accident when I just want to click a button on the application's tool bar.

Is there a way to increase this delay?

**Note:** This has been asked before, but as far as I can see, not recently ([this question asks about OSX Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35242/add-a-delay-to-menubar-dropdown-in-fullscreen-apps)) – the answer was “nope, not possible”, perhaps this has changed with Sierra / High Sierra?

Comment: It hasn’t changed it still isn’t possible to the best of my knowledge. You could pass this onto Apple: https://feedback.apple.com