# "citrix receiver" macOS menu bar delay on mouse pointer proximity

Tags: mac, mouse, menu-bar

I have this behaviour of *Citrix Receiver* on *MacOs Mojave* that when I take the mouse pointer close to the top of the screen. MacOs(parent OS) menubar shows up instantly. Which is very annoying considering that open new tab on browser inside citrix xendesktop is right at the top of the screen too.

I previously could set up a delay in showing menubar up, i.e. show after I keep the mouse pointer there for 5 seconds. However I can't find it any way to do it anymore.

Please help.

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70985/make-the-menu-bar-never-show-while-in-full-screen https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208393/change-delay-for-auto-hide-on-menu-bar?noredirect=1&lq=1 & https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312601/add-a-delay-for-displaying-the-menu-bar-when-app-is-in-fullscreen-mode

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. In August 2018, Citrix Receiver was superseded by Citrix Workspace. I use Citrix Workspace on Catalina and, when the remote session is in full-screen mode, there is a one-second delay before displaying the title bar. While the latest version of Citrix Workspace (version 20.9.0.17 (2009)) doesn't support Mojave, the previous version (20.08.0.3 (2008)) does. You may want to give it a try, It can be downloaded from here: https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/legacy-receiver-for-mac/workspace-app-for-mac-2008.html.